# Converting flat array to Id and Name object array using Lodash

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

```
let states = ["Georgia","California","FL","TX","MA","NJ"];
```

How do I convert the states array into Id and Name array collection using lodash.

Is there a way to convert the array in below format ( image shown below):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let states = ["Georgia","California","FL","TX","MA","NJ"];

const newObj = [];

_.each(states, state => newObj.push({ id: state, name: state }));

console.log(newObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

`_.each` performs a function on each item of an Array.  With that you can create a new object for each state and push that into a new Array.  Note: this could also be accomplished with JavaScript's built in `.map`.

----- UPDATE -----
Why did I make this complicated many years ago?

```js
const states = ["Georgia","California","FL","TX","MA","NJ"];

const newObj = states.map(state => ({ id: state, name: state }));

console.log(newObj);
```

No need to use `lodash`, just map through the array and return a new object for each item in the array.

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need lodash to do that.

```js
let states = ["Georgia","California","FL","TX","MA","NJ"];

let result = states.map((item) => {
return {
      id: item,
      name: item}})
console.log(result)
```

You do pretty much the same with lodash

```
import _ from 'lodash';

result = _.map(states, (item) => {
return {
      id: item,
      name: item}})
```

Comment: Thank you Vamshi, but your code with lodash isn't working, it says : Constructor Map requires 'new'

Comment: If you imported Map from lodash/map the way I did in the answer, it shouldn't complain, which explains you haven't imported Map from lodash/map

Comment: Using the alias `Map` for the lodash map could cause confusion with the native javascript [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: @GruffBunny I get it now. Updating my answer